# Word completion without hitting CTRL+SPACE

Tags: f#, visual-studio-2013, intellisense

From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hcw1s69b.aspx:

> Complete Word completes the rest of a variable, command, or function
>   name once you have entered enough characters to disambiguate the term.
>   You can invoke Complete Word by clicking Edit/IntelliSense/Complete
>   Word, typing CTRL+SPACE, or clicking the Complete Word button on the
>   editor toolbar.

Is there any way to make Complete Word autocompletion work as you type without having to hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SPACE</kbd>?

Comment: Please use the tags field, not the title, to specify which technologies you're using.

Answer (score 2):

Once the Intellisense selection menu pops up:

[image: Intellisense drop-down]

you can start typing. As soon as you have a selection:

[image: Intellisense with typing started]

you can hit **Enter** or **Space** to complete the word:

[image: Completed word]

Comment: Thanks, it works in this case (when you need to autocomplete something after `.` symbol, it's called "List Members" IIRC). But what if you wanted to do the same for `authors` or `printfn`? It seems like currently, with the default settings, hitting `Ctrl+Space` is necessary for this kind of autocompletion ("Word Completion").

Comment: That sounds correct; at least: I don't know of any other ways to do it, and I've been using Visual Studio since it had no version number :)